# How to pip install compiled python code and how to package it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package

I have a project in which I need to use pip to install a package. The package is something that I wrote and it includes a few files and directories. I used a setup.py file to package it and successfully used pip to bring it in my container. However I would like to compile the code so I don't have the source code up in the cloud. I still need to use pip to install the package.
I understand I can use compileall to compile it to produce a .pyc file.

1. How can I pip install compiled code?
2. Do I still need to use a setup.py file?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a wheel file. This is pip-installable.

Just follow this quide:)

https://www.realpythonproject.com/how-to-create-a-wheel-file-for-your-python-package-and-import-it-in-another-project/